# why we need to make pair in ng-option is select for Angular .? though we can make are work done witho

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Hi can any one tell me why we need to make "(k, v)" in

ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in types" as we can do are work done by writing 
ng-options="k as v for v in types" also.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <p>Select a car:</p>

 <select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="y.brand for (x, y) in cars">
     </select>

 <h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.brand}}</h1>
 <h2>Model: {{selectedCar.model}}</h2>
 <h3>Color: {{selectedCar.color}}</h3>

 <p>The visible text inside the dropdown list can also be a property of the value object.</p>

</div>

<script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.cars = {
          car01 : {brand : "Ford", model : "Mustang", color : "red"},
          car02 : {brand : "Fiat", model : "500", color : "white"},
          car03 : {brand : "Volvo", model : "XC90", color : "black"}
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Examples

```
ng-options="Single.Value as Single.Caption for Single in $ctrl.Example.Singles" 


ng-repeat="(indexSingle, Single) in ($ctrl.Example.Singles | filter:{IsVisible:true})"


ng-repeat="Single in $ctrl.Example.Singles"
```

you are curious about the middle one here is it in a example :

```
<div ng-repeat="(indexSingle, Single) in ($ctrl.Example.Singles | filter:{IsVisible:true})">
     Index = {{indexSingle}}
<div>
```

Comment: hi can you provide running jsfiddle .? for the better understanding.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought this would lighten you up enough, I cannot explain it properly.